# Problem while closing a geotiff file

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geotools

I have a method where I open a geotiff file and print its dimensions

```
    public void parseAndSaveFile(String pathFileToParse) throws IOException, Exception {

        GridCoverage2DReader reader = null;
        GridCoverage2D image        = null;
        BufferedImage img           = null;

        try {

            File f = new File(pathFileToParse);

            ParameterValue<OverviewPolicy> policy = AbstractGridFormat.OVERVIEW_POLICY.createValue();
            policy.setValue(OverviewPolicy.IGNORE);

            // this will basically read 4 tiles worth of data at once from the disk...
            ParameterValue<String> gridsize = AbstractGridFormat.SUGGESTED_TILE_SIZE.createValue();
            //gridsize.setValue(512 * 4 + "," + 512);

            // Setting read type: use JAI ImageRead (true) or ImageReaders read methods (false)
            ParameterValue<Boolean> useJaiRead = AbstractGridFormat.USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD.createValue();
            useJaiRead.setValue(true);

            reader = new GeoTiffReader(f);      
            //reader.read(new GeneralParameterValue[] { policy, gridsize, useJaiRead });
            image = reader.read(new GeneralParameterValue[]{policy, gridsize, useJaiRead});
            //Rectangle2D bounds2D = image.getEnvelope2D().getBounds2D();
            // calculate zoom level for the image
            GridGeometry2D geometry = image.getGridGeometry();

            img = ImageIO.read(f);
            //WritableRaster raster = img.getRaster();
            //int numBands = raster.getNumBands();

            int width   = img.getWidth();
            int height  = img.getHeight();


            logger.info("Width: {}, Height: {}", width, height);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            reader.dispose();
            image.dispose(true);
        }
    }
```

In the calling method, I try to delete the file

```
Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(pathFileToParse));
```

but I get the error:

**Unable to access the file. The file is used by another process.**

Because? Did I correctly release the geotiff file?

Comment: Try to see which other process is using the file - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565218/how-to-know-what-process-is-using-a-given-file

Comment: I saw the post and installed the "Handle" utility.
The only process which use the file is javaw.exe

Answer (score 1):

That code works perfectly for me on Linux, so unless you are doing something odd in the rest of the program it is a windows issue.

I added this `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
    ParseAndDelete me = new ParseAndDelete();

    String pathFileToParse = "test3.tif";
    me.parseAndSaveFile(pathFileToParse);
    Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(pathFileToParse));
  }
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: I don't know to explain why it doesn't work for me

Comment: even the changes you proposed to me do not work

Comment: so a program of just that main and your method fails on windows? It may be a bug but afaik none of the GeoTools devs uses windows so it is unlikely to get fixed.

Comment: the process that blocks the file is javaw.exe

Comment: I solved with these instructions:

FileInputStream tiffFile = new FileInputStream(pathFileToParse);
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(tiffFile);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(iis);

Just close the FileInputStream and I no longer have problems deleting the file.
If I try to close the ImageInputStream instead I have an error because it is already closed